# Twitter API - search tweets and filter by bio keywords

Tags: twitter

Is there any way at all to search for latest tweets by keyword, then - crucially - only show the tweets when the twitter user it belongs to has a keyword in their bio? I've been searching for ways to do this and have found nothing other than sites (e.g FollowerWonk) which offer this functionality but not an API to tap into. Any advice appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

You can use the regular Twitter api to search for Tweets containing your keyword. All docs are at dev.twitter.com. In the results set that you get back, you can also get the bio of each user. You could make a subselection in that text. We found the easiest way to load the results into a SOLR instance, and search on anything you want.

Comment: The problem is that the result set doesn't contain the bio of each user.